# Onde os bancos ficam salvos no SQL*Plus?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Eu baixei o SQL*Plus no site da Oracle, instalei (meu notebook é Windows 10) criei usuário e já criei alguns bancos, mas não sei onde ele salva os bancos que criei. Onde fica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em nenhum lugar. O [SQL*Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL*Plus) é um utilitário para uso de comandos, principalmente em *scripts* para manipular bancos de dados. Ele não é um banco de dados, então não tem porque estar em algum lugar.

Deve ter criado bases de dados no [Oracle Database](https://www.oracle.com/database/index.html) através do SQL * Plus. Os arquivos dele podem estar em qualquer lugar. É possível configurar isso. O mais adequado é consultar onde eles foram instalados. Pode consultar pelo SQL*Plus:

```
select name from v$datafile;
```

Também consultar por:

```
select value from v$parameter where name = 'db_create_file_dest'
```

Outra possibilidade:

```
select * from dba_data_files;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/FilesLocation.sql).

Há uma [documentação sobre o assunto](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/dfiles.htm).

Comment: Olá, instalei no windows 10, eu baixei o oracleXE11.
Eu ainda não consegui encontrar onde os bancos ficam salvos.